# Cast issue on app id when running New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've run into an error after following this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) when trying to set up an application access policy in powershell. This is the cmdlet that was run, which produced the error,

```
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity "MeetingsPolicy" -AppIds "<app-id>" -Description "MeetingsPolicy"
```

The error received in powershell is the following,

```
"New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSListModifier' to type
'System.String'."
```

Can anyone help shed any light on what is the problem here and how to fix it please?

P.S Im using Powershell 5.1 on Win 10 and running Powershell in admin mode.

Have also tried the following using "splatting", which also did not work.

```
$props = @{
     identity = 'MeetingsPolicy'
     appids = '<app-id>'
     description = 'MeetingsPolicy'
 } 
 New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy @props
```

Comment: Please cross check if you have provided proper <app-id> while running the command?

Comment: Yes the app-id is the correct one for my azure ad app registration

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out the Microsoft Teams cmdlet module version 3.1.0 has issues in there when installed with no previous version. I had to install the 2.3.2-preview version first, which allowed the cmdlets to work. I then updated this version to 3.1.0 and it works fine.

So the steps you need to take are the following,

```
i) Remove the teams module from powershell,
Uninstall-Module MicrosoftTeams -Allversions

ii) Install the older version first,
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -RequiredVersion 2.3.2-preview -AllowPrerelease

iii) Connect to teams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

v) Update to the latest version (Optional)
Update-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams
```

Run cmdlet and it should work now.

Credit to Marcus Rath for his post here https://blog.matrixpost.net/teams-powershell-several-cmdlet-doesnt-work-errounable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-management-automation-pslistmodifier-to-type-system-string/, which explains the issue in more detail.